# api call using async React native

Tags: html, react-native, api, networking

this is working in html its function is just to display a text

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script><script src="https://public.radio.co/playerapi/jquery.radiocoplayer.min.js"></script> 

<span
                    class="radioplayer"
                    data-src="https://s2.radio.co/s80551dbda/listen"
                    data-playbutton="false"
                    data-volumeslider="false"
                    data-elapsedtime="false"
                    data-nowplaying="true"
                    data-showplayer="false"
                    data-volume="100"
                  >
    <script>$('.radioplayer').radiocoPlayer();</script>
```

I want to implement this in react native using networking api call like so.
but i can't get anywhere!!

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue'
  })
});
```

Comment: This fetch function returns a promise, so you should use await keyword to get the result or using a then block at the end of fetch function

Comment: What error did you get with fetch?

Answer (score 0):

Try using axios, its is the best for api calls. https://github.com/axios/axios.